# Enqueued scripts and styles loading in WordPress Dashboard as well

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

For a moment, I wondered if my test site got hacked -- my WordPress site's dashboard was all broken (cosmetically). But when i looked at the source code of the page, I noticed that the "scripts and styles" that I enqueued for the front-end were also enqueued in the backend as well.

This is how I did it:

```
add_action('init','wpse54189_register_script');
function wpse54189_register_script(){

    wp_register_script( 'aahan_bootstrap_transition', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-transition.js');
    wp_register_script( 'aahan_bootstrap_carousel', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-carousel.js');
    wp_register_script( 'aahan_bootstrap_carousel_cycler', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-carousel-cycler.js', array('jquery', 'aahan_bootstrap_transition', 'aahan_bootstrap_carousel'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aahan_bootstrap_carousel_cycler' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    wp_register_script( 'aahan_ajax_comment', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/no-reload-comments.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'aahan_ajax_comment', 'yjlSettings', array(
         'gifUrl'=> get_template_directory_uri().'/images/ajax-loader.gif',
         'autoGrow'=> 'enable'
    ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'aahan_ajax_comment' );

}

add_action('init','aahan_register_style');
function aahan_register_style(){
    wp_register_style( 'aahan_webfonts_stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri().'/font/font.css');
    wp_register_style( 'aahan_main_stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css', array('aahan_webfonts_stylesheet'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'aahan_main_stylesheet' );
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "init" action runs both on frontend page loads, and on backend page loads.

Try hooking these to the "wp_enqueue_scripts" action instead. I believe it does not run on admin page loads.

**Example Code: (By OP)**

```
function wpse54388_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( ... );

    wp_enqueue_script( ... );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse54388_scripts_styles' );
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But how about styles? There doesn't seem to be an "action" called `wp_enqueue_styles".

Comment: You use the same hook for both scripts and styles. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: @mrwweb Good call. Digital high-five!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the condition

```
if( is_admin() ) return;
```

So you will have

```
add_action('init','wpse54189_register_script');
function wpse54189_register_script(){
    if( is_admin() ) return;
.....
}

add_action('init','aahan_register_style');
function aahan_register_style(){

    if( is_admin() ) return;
.....
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the only hooks that should be used with `wp_enqueue_style()` or `wp_enqueue_script()` are "wp_enqueue_scripts" or "admin_enqueue_scripts". If someone wants to enqueue a script on both the front and backend, they can use `wp_register_script()` (or style) once and then enqueue it with just the handle on both hooks.