# Theme Loading Into Dashboard

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I'm having this really weird, never seen before, issue ... whenever I visit the Dashboard, after about 3-5 seconds, my theme loads into the Dashboard layout. It's like the theme's stylesheet is being enqueued somehow ...

[image]

Here is my enqueue hook within `functions.php`:

```
function myyogawebsite_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-min-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/foundation.min.css' );

    // WordPress Core
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wordpress-core-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/wp-core.css' );

    // Load our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myyogawebsite-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', null, null, false);

    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.js', null, null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', array('foundation-jquery'), null, true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myyogawebsite_scripts' );
```

Comment: Well, _is_ it being enqueued? :) Do you see it in page source or in browser's dev tools log of resources being loaded?

Comment: Well, I see it being loaded, but I have no idea why it is ... my functions.php file is pretty simple. I'll post it above.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am having the same issue. It occurs whether or not I have my theme or 2014 loaded - with plugins turned off, etc. I deleted Wordpress folders wp-admin and wp-includes, and all files except .htaccess and wp-config.php. Still loads all css into dashboard with the site appearing under wordpress news.

Comment: See [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54386/enqueued-scripts-and-styles-loading-in-wordpress-dashboard-as-well/54388#54388)

Comment: @ECarterYoung -- the OP appears to be using the correct hook (`wp_enqueue_scripts` vs. `init` in the link you posted).

Comment: What is the Theme Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm experiencing the exact same problem, and it makes using the editor very difficult. I can only assume that it is a bug with one of the newer versions of WordPress in certain scenarios / configurations.

Until it gets fixed properly my workaround is to wrap my enqueue statements in an `if` statement for `!is_admin()`.

For example, in your case:

```
function myyogawebsite_scripts() {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-min-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/foundation.min.css' );

        // WordPress Core
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wordpress-core-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/wp-core.css' );

        // Load our main stylesheet.
        wp_enqueue_style( 'myyogawebsite-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', null, null, false);

        wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.js', null, null, true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', array('foundation-jquery'), null, true);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myyogawebsite_scripts' );
```

See how that works for you. What version of WordPress are you using, and what platform is your website hosted on (eg. Linux, Windows). I'm on WP4.0 on Windows.